# How to configure caching for Sitecore Item Web API?

Tags: caching, sitecore, sitecore6

How is caching configured when using the Sitecore Item Web API?

When reading data from Sitecore using the Sitecore Item Web API I'd like to configure caching so requests for the same data set can be served from cache.

It appears the Sitecore Caching documentation along with the Sitecore Item Web API 1.0.0 Developer's Guide don't cover setting this up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It automatically serves data from the cache already.  It does this by default.

If you want something specific..i.e. the content displayed via a specific sublayout, you can set your own "please cache this" on layout/sublayout/rendering items with the checkboxes in the caching area and the Cachable box where you can tell Sitecore to cache the content and if necessary a vary by based on a number of different aspects (i.e. varybylogin, varybydevice, etc.)

You can view the cache sizes via /sitecore/admin/cache.aspx or there is at least one cache manager module that is more in depth.